# Как отключить или заблокировать командную строку в DOS

Tags: dos

Чистый DOS или FreeDOS. Необходим аналог Windows Lock

Comment: Напишите на любом языке. программа то несколько строчек будет. заблокировать прерывание по Ctrl+C и спрашивать пароль в цикле пока не введут

Comment: Да, конечно была такая идея. А есть ли готовые решения? Или встроенное в ядро как у Linux?

Comment: В ядре ДОС такого нет. Значит, придётся реализовывать собственной программой. Готовых, думаю, тоже нет - во времена голого ДОСа подобная фича вряд ли была кому-то актуальна.

Answer (score -2):

Насколько я в курсе, это невозможно.